# Get js variable transpiled by Symfony4 Webpack Encore in twig / FosJsRouting bundle

Tags: javascript, twig, symfony4, webpack-encore, fosjsroutingbundle

I use fos_js_routing bundle on symfony4 . I need to get the Routing object reachable in my twig view. I defined Routing in assets/js/app.js, a transpiled js file with Webpack Encore.
Because my Routing object is correctly built in this file, 
I want to access it in a Twig view.

```
// assets/js/app.js
const routes = require('../../web/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
```

I got this line in my webpack config:

```
Encore      
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  .setPublicPath('/build')
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
```

I get my twig view, where the transpiled app.js is reachable and succesfully transpiled by webpack Encore. But the variable Routing is not reachable ( I got client error : Routing is not defined),

```
 // in my twig view, inside a script block
 var redirectionUrl = Routing.generate('my_route', {arg: arg}); // Routing is not defined
```

probably because is defined as **let** in the transpilation process, and I want it as a **var**, to be reachable in each twig view where I include transpiled app.js ( public/build/js/app.js ). My Twig view is including the transpiled file in this line, and succesfully imported in my twig sources

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

How can I get Routing in my twig view using Webpack encore ?

Comment: For that to work, routing has to have a default export. Also, mixing ESM and require syntax in source will bite you, sooner than later

Comment: can i get more information with your answer please ? ( i tried to use import / export  ES6 syntax but unsuccesfully used theses features in my twig template ) thanks for your support

Comment: I don't want to add answer because there isn't enough detail for me to be certain. What I meant was do not mix import and require and make sure that `'../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js'` contains something like `exports.default = something` or that you are using an ES module interop aware loader or bundler like Webpack or SystemJS and or a properly configured transpiler such as bable or typescript

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AUTO ANSWER :

As far as i understood ( please comment if I'm wrong ), because **Webpack** is transpiling **ES6** syntax to **ES5** syntax and because in this process all useless and unrevelant data is erased in your production js transpiled files 
( when you call the command: **node_modules/.bin/encore production** ). So as far as i know, **you cannot pass unused data between ES6 js file transpiled to an ES5 js file with Encore**. Maybe entering in advanced configuration of Webpack but i didnt spend the time for that ( and this is not usually what you want to deal with transpilers ). My using of **fosjsrouting bundle** in my project wasn't essential, so I just removed it. But today i will explain how to properly load **fosjsrouting Routing object** from your twig templates ( instead of trying to access it from your Encore transpiled js files ).

---

1- [Read documentation of FosJsRouting Bundle here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html)
in order to :

--- **A/** Install the bundle

--- **B/** Build your routes

I don't remember the commands, but everything is well explained in the documentation link provided.
At the end of your bundle installation, you must get :

1 - **router.min.js** file in your **public/** folder => **./public/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js**

2 - **fos_js_routes.json** in your **public/** folder =>
**./public/js/fos_js_routes.json**

---

Now I show you how to generate a Route on a basic twig template view.

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block javascripts %}


    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js')}}"> 
    </script>

    <script>

        var r = Routing; // loaded from router.min.js

        // because ES5 doesnt support require syntax, 
        // we use jquery getJSON function in order to set 
        // routing data to our Routing object
        $.getJSON("{{ asset('js/fos_js_routes.json')}}", function(routes) { 

            console.log(routes); 

            r.setRoutingData(routes);

            console.log(r.generate('my_route'));

        });

     </script>


{% endblock %}
```